# URLs with hypen - converting MS Word to PDF

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, pdf, hyperlink

I'm writing a document with MS Word for Mac 2011. This documents uses a lot of URLs that are also hyperlinks. When converting the document to a PDF by using the save as... option, the URLs that contain a hyphen are mis-formed. All the other hyperlinks are working correctly.

Instead of a hyphen, I see that the URL has some special escaping characters.

What can I do to avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the font of the URL to Arial in Word before creating the PDF. I found that changing the font from Calibri to Arial solved a similar issue. See [this answer on the Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2008-macword/hyphens-in-a-hyperlink-creating-pdf-makes-2/ea3d997d-3e77-456c-94ca-6f0544043e62).

Here is a precise description of the problem that I was having. When I create a PDF with Word for Mac 2011 from a document that contains URLs with hyphens (-), the URLs in the PDF have  double hyphens (--) and are therefore invalid. I create PDFs using the **Print** command, and then select **Save as PDF** or **Open in Preview** from the dialog box. I encounter this problem when downloading documents from Google Docs in Word (.docx) format. Google uses Calibri as the default font for body text in documents. I suspect there is some confusion in the font definition of hyphens and dashes when the PDF is generated (dashes are longer than hyphens, so [dashes are typically represented as two hyphens](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/3/7/98/) when a font does not have a dash character).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may not be the answer you'd like to hear, but Word is definitely not perfect in exporting to PDF. If I was you, I would consider installing some **simple app acting as PDF-printer** (e.g. [**doPDF**](http://www.dopdf.com/)) and generating perfectly valid PDF files.

The adventage is that such virtual printer allows you to generate proper PDF files from any application supporting Print option...